# mod rewriterule for redirect to login session or index page

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, oracle-http-server

For OHS (Oracle HTTP Server)/Apache, I am trying to write a Mod rewrite rule

User URL

```
https://url/console
```

Target URL

```
https://url/product/faces/login  (If new session)  
https://url/product/faces/index  (If already authenticated in previous sessions)
```

Following is what I wrote, but its not working

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteRule ^/console /product/faces/login [R]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the .htaccess file or Apache configuration for redirecting users based on their session state involves a bit more than just using mod_rewrite. mod_rewrite alone cannot directly check the session state because that typically requires running some logic to determine whether the user is authenticated. However, there is a workaround using mod_rewrite in combination with some server-side scripting that can enable this functionality.
Here's an approach to handle the redirection using mod_rewrite and server-side scripting.

1.Enable rewrite engine and set the base:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

2.Redirect all /console requests to a script:

```
RewriteRule ^console$ /session_check.php [L]
```

3.Create a session_check.php script that checks the user's session and outputs an appropriate redirect response.
Example session_check.php:

```
<?php

session_start();

// Check if the user is authenticated.
if (!isset($_SESSION['authenticated']) || $_SESSION['authenticated'] !== true) {
  // User is not authenticated, so redirect to the login page.
  header('Location: /product/faces/login');
  exit;
} else {
  // User is authenticated, so redirect to the index page.
  header('Location: /product/faces/index');
  exit;
}

?>
```

Ensure that your PHP is configured correctly to handle sessions, and the session_start(); call can actually restore session data.
Keep in mind that this approach requires that somewhere in your application logic when users are authenticated, you set $_SESSION['authenticated'] to true.
Please replace /session_check.php with the actual path where you want to place this server-side script. Also note that this script is simplified for demonstration purposes, and real-world authentication checks would need to be more robust and secure.
Once you've completed these steps, every time a user navigates to https://url/console, the mod_rewrite rule will pass the request to the session_check.php script, which then determines whether to redirect the user to the login or index page depending on their session state.
This is just one example, and based on the specifics of your setup or the functionalities of the Oracle HTTP Server (OHS), which is based on Apache, you might need to modify the approach or configuration. Always ensure that any redirection and authentication handling is done over secure connections (HTTPS) to keep user data safe.

Thank you.